# как обьявить конструктор в абстрактной фабрике?

Tags: c#, абстрактная-фабрика

```
class Program
    {
        abstract class R2Factory
        {
            public abstract AbstractProductPloshina CreateProductPloshina();
            public abstract AbstractProductProstir CreateProductProstir();
        }
        class ConcreteFactoryR2 : R2Factory
        {
            private int a11, a12,a13,a14,a21,a22,a23,a24,a31,a32,a33,a34,x,y,z;
            public ConcreteFactoryR2(int a11,int a12,int a13,int a14,int a21, int a22, int a23, int a24, int a31, int a32, int a33, int a34, int x, int y, int z)
            {
                this.a11 = a11;
                this.a12 = a12;
                this.a13 = a13;
                this.a14 = a14;this.a21 = a21;this.a22 = a22;this.a23 = a23;this.a24 = a24;this.a31 = a31;
                this.a32 = a32;this.a33 = a33;this.a34 = a34;this.x = x;this.y = y; this.z = z;
            }
            public override AbstractProductPloshina CreateProductPloshina()
            {
                return new ProductPloshina(a11,a12,a13,a21,a22,a23,x,y);
            }

            public override AbstractProductProstir CreateProductProstir()
            {
                return new ProductProstir(a11,a12,a13,a14,a21,a22,a23,a24,a31,a32,a33,a34,x,y,z);
            }
        }


        abstract class AbstractProductPloshina
        {
            public abstract void Show();
            public abstract void Output();
        }

        abstract class AbstractProductProstir
        {
            public abstract void Show();
            public abstract void Output();
        }

        class ProductPloshina : AbstractProductPloshina
        {
            private int a11,a12,a13,a21,a22,a23,x,y;


            public ProductPloshina(int a11, int a12,int a13,int a21, int a22, int a23, int x, int y)
            {
                this.a11 = a11;
                this.a12 = a12;
                this.a13 = a13;
                this.a21 = a21;
                this.a22 = a22;
                this.a23 = a23;
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }
            public override void Show()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Коефiцiєнти перетворення: a11,a12,a13,a21,a22,a23");
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}", a11, a12, a13, a21, a22, a23);
                Console.WriteLine("Точка: ({0},{1})", x, y);
            }
            public override void Output()
            {
                int X = a11 * x + a12 * y + a13;
                int Y = a21 * x + a22 * y + a23;
                Console.WriteLine("Образ точки ({0},{1}): ({2},{3})", x, y, X, Y);
            }
        }

        class ProductProstir : AbstractProductProstir
        {
            private int a11, a12, a13, a14, a21, a22, a23, a24, a31, a32, a33, a34, x, y, z;
            public ProductProstir(int a11, int a12,int a13, int a14, int a21, int a22, int a23, int a24, int a31, int a32, int a33, int a34, int x, int y, int z)
            {
                this.a11 = a11;
                this.a12 = a12;this.a13 = a13;this.a14 = a14;this.a21 = a21;this.a22 = a22;this.a23 = a23;this.a24 = a24;this.a31 = a31;
                this.a32 = a32; this.a33 = a33; this.a34 = a34;
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.z = z;
            }
            public override void Show()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Коефiцiєнти перетворення: a11,a12,a13,a14,a21,a22,a23,a24,a31,32,a33,a34");
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11}", a11, a12, a13, a14, a21, a22, a23, a24, a31, a32, a33, a34);
                Console.WriteLine("Точка: ({0},{1},{2})", x, y, z);
            }
            public override void Output()
            {

                int X = a11 * x + a12 * y + a13 * z + a14;
                int Y = a21 * x + a22 * y + a23 * z + a24;
                int Z = a31 * x + a32 * y + a33 * z + a34;
                Console.WriteLine("Образ точки ({0},{1},{2}): ({3},{4},{5})", x, y, z, X, Y, Z);
            }
        }


        class Client
        {
            private AbstractProductPloshina abstractProductA;
            private AbstractProductProstir abstractProductB;

            public Client(R2Factory factory1)
            {
                abstractProductB = factory1.CreateProductProstir();
                abstractProductA = factory1.CreateProductPloshina();
            }
            public void Run()
            {
                abstractProductA.Show();
            }

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}`введите сюда код`
```

Comment: class ProductPloshina : AbstractProductPloshina
        {
            public int a11 { get; set; }
            public int a12 { get; set; }
            public ProductPloshina(int a11, int  a12)
            {
                this.a11 = a11;
                this.a12 = a12;
            }
        }

Comment: @Igor мне нужно добавить функции с конструктором в основном классе, только я не знаю как обьявить

Comment: А я не знаю, что такое "основной класс".

Comment: @Igor ProductProstir и ProductPloshina

Comment: Я смотрю, идею Вы уловили ).

Comment: только я не знаю как создать обьекты класа ProductProstir и ProductPloshina, пыталась создать Client для каждого @Igor

Comment: я сделала Client и ConcreteFactory для каждого

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем Вам в ней конструктор?

```
class ConcreteFactoryR2 : R2Factory
{ 
    private int a11;
    private int a12;

    public ConcreteFactoryR2(int a11, int a12)
    {
      this.a11 = a11;
      this.a12 = a12;
    }

    public override AbstractProductPloshina CreateProductPloshina()
    {
        return new ProductPloshina(a11, a12);
    }

    public override AbstractProductProstir CreateProductProstir()
    {
        return new ProductProstir(a11, a12);
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
  Client client = new Client(new ConcreteFactoryR2(123, 456));
  client.Run();
}
```

Comment: а как обьявить переменные через  Client для плоскости и для пространства?